# If statements only runs the else condition even though the if condition is true

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm making a push-up log that requires to see if the text file it generates contains the date, so that it knows to add onto the counting list, or start on a new line with a new date.

I made this dummy search to see if it will work.

```
from datetime import date

with open("Push-Ups-Log.txt", "a+") as Counter:
    AllLogs = Counter.read()
    if str(date.today()) in AllLogs:
        print("True")
    else:
        print("False")
```

The text file looks like this:

```
1. 2022-07-21
```

Python output:

```
False
```

Any reason why?

Comment: @AndyLester You have to import a module: from datetime import date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you open a file in `'a+'` mode the file pointer is at the end of the file if the file exists. So `AllLogs` is an empty string.
So you should issue `seek` method to position file pointer to beginning of the file

```
from datetime import date

with open("Push-Ups-Log.txt", "a+") as Counter:
    Counter.seek(0)
    AllLogs = Counter.read()
    if str(date.today()) in AllLogs:
        print("True")
    else:
        print("False")
```

Comment: Spot on.  I will suggest using ```*f*``` instead of OP's ```Counter``` as the file pointer.  It's really a confusing variable name.  +1